# Skip Timeout expression field not available in Twilio Java Helper Library

Tags: twilio, twilio-taskrouter

I am trying to create a Workflow using Twilio Java SDK (7.40.0). I have the requirement to set the 'Skip Timeout expression' (https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter/worker-presence) as part of the Routing step. But i am unable to find a field for setting the 'Skip Timeout expression' in WorkflowRuleTarget class. How do i set this field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When creating a workflow through the API the configuration should be presented as a JSON string (see [the example below, from the docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter/api/workflows?code-sample=code-create-new-workflow-4&code-language=Java&code-sdk-version=7.x)). `skip_if` is part of the configuration, so should just be part of that JSON.

```
    Twilio.init(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN);
    Workflow workflow = Workflow.creator(
            "WSXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
            "Sales, Marketing, Support Workflow",
            "{\"task_routing\": {\"filters\": [{\"expression\": \"type=='sales'\", \"targets\": [{\"queue\": \"WQXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\"}]}, {\"expression\": \"type=='marketing'\", \"targets\": [{\"queue\": \"WQXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\"}]}, {\"expression\": \"type=='support'\", \"targets\": [{\"queue\": \"WQXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\"}]}], \"default_filter\": {\"queue\": \"WQXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\"}}}")
        .setAssignmentCallbackUrl(
            URI.create("http://example.com"))
        .setFallbackAssignmentCallbackUrl(
            URI.create("http://example2.com"))
        .setTaskReservationTimeout(30)
        .create();
```

Comment: I am accepting the answer as a workaround. We are using `WorkflowRuleTarget` class for building the configuration and finally serializing to string. So a field for *skip_if* in `WorkflowRuleTarget` class would be the ideal solution. Hopefully the java SDK will be updated in future release.